# Order By Id and Limit Offset By Id from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an issue similar to the following query:

```
select name, number, id
from tableName
order by id 
limit 10 offset 5
```

But in this case I only take the 10 elements from the group with offset 5
Is there a way to set limit and offset by id?

For example if I have a set:

```
|------------------------------------|---|---------------------------------------|
| Ana                                | 1 | 589d0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651  |
| Jana                               | 2 | 589d0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651  |
| Jan                                | 3 | 589d0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651  |
| Joe                                | 2 | 64ed0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651  |
```

and if I have skip 1 I should get

```
|------------------------------------|---|---------------------------------------|
| Jana                               | 2 | 589d0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651  |
| Jan                                | 3 | 589d0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651  |
```

Comment: What do you mean "offset by id"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Enumerate records in CTE and restrict by this number according to ID value.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question

Comment: For example if I have a set:  
Ana, 1 , 589d0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651  
Jana, 2 , 589d0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651  
Jan, 3, 589d0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651  
Joe, 2, 64ed0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651  
and if I have skip 1  
I should get  
Jana, 2 , 589d0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651  
Jan, 3, 589d0011-ef54-4708-a64a-f85228149651

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want to filter by `row_number()`:

```
select name, number, id
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by name order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where 
    rn >= :number_of_records_per_group_to_skip
    and rn < :number_of_records_per_group_to_skip + :number_of_records_per_group_to_keep
```

The query ranks records by `id` withing groups of records having the same `name`, and then filters using two parameters:

- `:number_of_records_per_group_to_skip`: how many records per group should be skipped
- `:number_of_records_per_group_to_skip`: how many records per group should be kept (after skipping `:number_of_records_per_group_to_skip` records)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but it gives you the results your example shows:

```
select name, number, id
from (
   select * from tableName
   order by id 
   limit 3 offset 0
) d
where id > 1;
```

Best regards,
Bjarni